# How to count the number of sub string from a split in java

Tags: java, string, split

I have this piece of code in my java class

```
mystring  = mysuperstring.split("/");
```

I want to know how many sub-string is created from the split.

In normal situation, if i want to access the first sub-string i just write

```
mystring[0];
```

Also, i want to know if `mystring[5]` exist or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I want to know how many sub-string is created from the split.

Since `mystring` is an array, you can simply use `mystring.length` to get the number of substrings.

> Also, i want to know if `mystring[5]` exist or not.

To do this:

```
if (mystring.length >= 6) { ... }
```

Comment: so i want to check if mystring[5] exist, i must write if(mystring.length==5) { do something }

Comment: @sameer: `if (mystring.length >= 6) { ... }`

Answer (score 10):

```
mystring  = mysuperstring.split("/");
int size = mystring.length;
```

remember that arrays are zero indexed, so where length = 5, the last element will be indexed with 4.

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple way to count the sub-strings

```
word.split('/').length;
```

You can see an example of this implementation [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-hangman-app/index.html/?cm_mmc=developerWorks-_-dW%20CloudOE%20content-_-j-hangman-app-_-article).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one & tell me if it works.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CountSubstring {
    public static int countSubstring(String subStr, String str){
        // the result of split() will contain one more element than the delimiter
        // the "-1" second argument makes it not discard trailing empty strings
        return str.split(Pattern.quote(subStr), -1).length - 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(countSubstring("th", "the three truths"));
        System.out.println(countSubstring("abab", "ababababab"));
        System.out.println(countSubstring("a*b", "abaabba*bbaba*bbab"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must read about split and array, please find the links.

if you read about **[split function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)** it returns `Array of String`.

and now you should read about **[Array and its size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)**

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to demo a dumy token validation. So I tried to `split` by dot (`.`). It did not worked. So, I wonder and checked out an hour with no luck. After a while, when randomly trying I added escape character before dot and thank god it worked :D.

The reason is `split` takes string as regex. I checked why when writing an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833008/java-string-split-with-dot):

> You are splitting on the regex ., which means "any character"

```
int len = accessToken.split("\\.").length;
```

String I wanted to check

```
String accessToken = Bearer 1111.1111.11111 // demonstration purpose dumy
```

Output:

```
3
```