# Java string split with "." (dot)

Tags: java, regex, string, split, indexoutofboundsexception

Why does the second line of this code throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

```
String filename = "D:/some folder/001.docx";
String extensionRemoved = filename.split(".")[0];
```

While this works:

```
String driveLetter = filename.split("/")[0];
```

I use Java 7.

Comment: Doesn't split use a regex string? In that case "." means any character.

Comment: ...and it's a DOUBLE backslash to delimit.

Answer (score 956, accepted):

You need to escape the dot if you want to split on a *literal* dot:

```
String extensionRemoved = filename.split("\\.")[0];
```

Otherwise you are splitting on the regex `.`, which means "any character".
Note the double backslash needed to create a single backslash in the regex.

---

You're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because your input string is just a dot, ie `"."`, which is an edge case that produces an empty array when split on dot; [`split(regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) removes all trailing blanks from the result, but since splitting a dot on a dot leaves only two blanks, after trailing blanks are removed you're left with an empty array.

To avoid getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for this edge case, use the overloaded version of [`split(regex, limit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-), which has a second parameter that is the size limit for the resulting array. When `limit` is *negative*, the behaviour of removing trailing blanks from the resulting array is disabled:

```
".".split("\\.", -1) // returns an array of two blanks, ie ["", ""]
```

ie, when `filename` is just a dot `"."`, calling `filename.split("\\.", -1)[0]` will return a blank, but calling `filename.split("\\.")[0]` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Note that filename can contain multiple dots. One must use the last index of "." and use that to find the substring of the filename.

Comment: @saurabheights The question was not about a correct regex, but rather why there was a an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. That said, you are incorrect: You don't need to know where the last dot is; you just need the right regex: `filename.split("\\.(?=[^.]*$)")`. This uses a *look ahead* to assert there are no dots anywhere in the input that follows the matching dot.

Comment: @emma you can delete them yourself via the “delete” link just beneath the question

Comment: A cleaner solution : str.split(Pattern.quote("."))[0]

Comment: To split by a dot, you actually need to add four backslashes such as:

Comment: @TomRutchik you actually **don't** need four backslashes: See [live demo](https://ideone.com/IvQNo1).

Comment: I've been testing this out interactively in an Eclipse IDE.  Only 4 blackslashes worked! I would get an exception if I only used 2 blackslashes.

Comment: Bohemian, you are right.  It appears the Eclipse IDE has problems evaluating expressions that contain strings containing escape sequences.  I didn't know that. I only use the Eclipse IDE to debug Java servlets. The eclipse expression evaluator will work for escaped stings if you add another level of escaping; which is why 4 backslashes worked for me but 2 wouldn't. Well that's life in the trenches!

Comment: @TomRutchik Expression evaluators will display `"\."` (the correct regex) for a String that is coded using the *String literal* `"\\."` - to put a backslash (Hava's escape character) in a String when writing a String literal you escape the escape character.

Answer (score 140):

The dot "." is a special character in java regex engine, so you have to use "\\." to escape this character:

```
final String extensionRemoved = filename.split("\\.")[0];
```

Comment: It is _not_ a special character in Java. It's a special character in Java's regex engine.

Comment: I just wasn't very accurate in my response but I agree with you. thanks for the precision ;)

Comment: It's a distinction worth making. Also, I just realized that I messed up a bit myself; it is a special char in Java, but that's not why it's causing a problem here. Anyway.

Answer (score 35):

This is because `.` is a reserved character in regular expression, representing any character.
Instead, we should use the following statement:

```
String extensionRemoved = filename.split("\\.")[0];
```

Answer (score 21):

I believe you should escape the dot. Try:

```
String filename = "D:/some folder/001.docx";
String extensionRemoved = filename.split("\\.")[0];
```

Otherwise dot is interpreted as any character in regular expressions.

Comment: A cleaner solution : str.split(Pattern.quote("."))[0]