# Java string -> two numbers

Tags: java, regex

The operation I'm hoping to perform is to go from:

```
String "32.63578..."
```

to:

```
float 32.63
long 578... //where '...' is rest of string
```

Something like the following in Python:

```
split = str.find('.')+2
float = str[:split]
long = str[split:]
```

I'm new to Java, so I began by trying to look up equivalents, however it seems like a more convoluted solution than perhaps a regex would be? Unless there's more similar functions to python than splitting into a char array, and repeatedly iterating over?

Comment: see java.substring method.. Then Float.parseFloat and Long.parseLong method

Comment: I'm guessing, here, but it looks like you *actually* want a BigDecimal.

Comment: @StinePike `substring` doesn't help, I don't know the index, need to 'find' the decimal point.

Comment: I strongly recommend learning to use Javadocs.  But the methods you need are `indexOf` and `substring`.

Comment: I'm guessing too, but I don't think so. They're separate numbers, unrelated, being read from a string.

Comment: That is possible but it's not what OP was asking for.

Comment: @OllieFord Why do you have two unrelated numbers that aren't delimited in a string? It sounds like a headache to work with.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833008/java-string-split-with-dot and then use Float.parseFloat and Long.parseLong as @StinePike mentioned

Comment: @DavidWallace `indexOf` was what I couldn't find, thanks.

Comment: @Floris It's got the smells of an X-Y Problem.

Comment: If the OP wants exactly 32.63 (with that scale) then that's what he is going to need.

Comment: @BheshGurung - it is unclear how many digits the second number has...

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do, here? I can't think of a reason to split a number like this.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann It's not *a* number, it's two.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen plenty of cases of file formats involving fixed-width fields without separators, where you split what _looks like_ one number, at a particular position, because it's really two numbers.  Less common these days, but 20 years ago, this would have been quite a normal thing to want to do.

Comment: @OllieFord fair enough, but why no delimiter? It seems rather brittle this way.

Comment: @DavidWallace I'd rather at least have a struct with two big-endian values, then. Or a float and a varint. Data can be stored more efficiently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `indexOf` and `substring` methods:

```
String str = "32.63578";
int i = str.indexOf(".") + 3;
String part1 = str.substring(0, i);     // "32.63"
String part2 = str.substring(i);        // "578"

float num1 = Float.parseFloat(part1);   // 32.63
long num2 = Long.parseLong(part2);      // 578
```

Comment: Yes. And then convert these strings to the numerical type desired.

Comment: @Floris, I added convert part. Thank you for comment.

Comment: @falsetru happy to help make a good-ish answer good enough to get my vote!

Comment: If you're going to give two answers, you should really give them as two separate answers.  Someone may wish to upvote one and downvote the other.

Comment: @DavidWallace, I see. deleted the regular expression alternative.

Comment: Why don't you post it as a second answer?  You're allowed!  And someone may learn something from it, which is kind of the point of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidWallace, added the regular expression alternative as separated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression alternative:

```
String str = "32.63578";
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=\\.\\d{2})");
System.out.println(parts[0]); // "32.63"
System.out.println(parts[1]); // "578"
```

About the regular expression used:

```
(?<=\.\d{2})
```

It's positive lookbehind (`?<=...)`. It matches at the position where is preceded by `.` and 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [split method in String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) if you want to cleanly break the two parts.

However, if you want to have trailing decimals like in your example, you'll probably want to do something like this:

```
String str = "32.63578...";
String substr1, substr2;

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
  if (str.charAt(i) == '.')
  {
    substr1 = str.substring(0, i + 3);
    substr2 = str.substring(i + 3, str.length());
    break;
  }
}

//convert substr1 and substr2 here
```

Comment: @Floris are you sure?

Comment: @Floris it's cleaner, but the efficiency is probably exactly the same. After all, getting the index of a character means looping somehow.

Comment: @DavidWallace - Maybe not in execution time, but in number of characters used. I think it is good practice to use a function when it is "just right" for the job.

Comment: I agree that it's good practice not to do what this respondent has done.  I just can't see that it's less efficient than using `indexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s ="32.63578";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<Start>\\d{1,10}.\\d{1,2})(?<End>\\d{1,10})");
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (match.find()) {
        String start = match.group("Start");
        String ending = match.group("End");
        System.out.println(start);
        System.out.println(ending);
    }
```