# How to split a double number by dot into two decimal numbers in Java?

Tags: java

Trying to split a double number into two decimal parts by dot. Like  this: 1.9 into 1 and 9; 0.16 into  0 and 16;

Here's what I do, but seems a little redundant, what's the best way to do this?

The origin number will always be like Just 0.x or 1.x or 0.xx or 1.xx and xx > 10

```
    double d = 1.9;
    int a, b;
    String dString = Double.toString(d);
    String aString = dString.substring(0, 1);

    String bString = dString.substring(2);
    a = Integer.parseInt(aString);
    b = Integer.parseInt(bString);
```

My way of doing this seems using to much String conversion,which I don't think is very efficient.

Comment: You could use String.split(".")

Comment: What do you expect when the given number is `1.1`, `1.01`, `1.001`, etc?

Comment: @Marco: You mean `String.split("\\.")`

Comment: @ntalbs there's no such numbers in my case .Just 0.x or 1.x or 0.xx or 1.xx and  xx > 10

Comment: @Keppil: You're right!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try this way too

```
    double val=1.9;
    String[] arr=String.valueOf(val).split("\\.");
    int[] intArr=new int[2];
    intArr[0]=Integer.parseInt(arr[0]); // 1
    intArr[1]=Integer.parseInt(arr[1]); // 9
```

Comment: @Rucbira.. I am not clear with the `split("\\.")` part.. isn't the `split(".")` part enough?

Comment: @KidusTekeste see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833008/java-string-split-with-dot. *You need to escape the dot if you want to split on a literal dot*

Comment: Yes.. I have checked it.. got it now. Thanks @frianH

Answer (score 4):

You could treat the double like a string, and split it on the decimal place.

```
     double d = 13454.92345;
     String bob = Double.toString(d);
     String[] convert = bob.split("\\.");

     int a = Integer.parseInt(convert[0]);
     int b = Integer.parseInt(convert[1]);

     System.out.println(a); // 13454
     System.out.println(b); // 92345
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the decimal part as an `int` is not really following any standards, so you are stuck with your special solution for that. Getting the value before the decimal point can be simplified to a simple cast though:

```
double d = 1.9;
int a, b;
String dString = Double.toString(d);
String bString = dString.substring(2);
a = (int) d;
b = Integer.parseInt(bString);
```

Note that the `substring()` and `parseInt()` fails if the number is 10 or bigger though. You might want to change the `substring()` call to something like:

```
String bString = dString.split("\\.")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double num=12.5;
String str=Double.toString(num);
String strarray[]=str.split("\\.");
```

Now `strarray[0]` will be holding 12, and `strarray[1]` will be having 5.You can convert them into  integers by writing following code:

```
int num1=Integer.parseInt(strarray[0]);
int num2=Integer.parseInt(strarray[1]);
```

Comment: Make sure that you split on "." WITH "\\."

Answer (score 1):

Here's a two line version:

```
int a = (int)d;
int b = Integer.parseInt((d + "").split("\\.", 2)[1]).replaceAll("^$", "0"));
```

The first part is easy - just cast to `int`, which automatically chops off any decimal part of the number.

The second part is easiest with a Strimg approach - split the string version on a dot and use the second part. Note the addition of `""` which generates a string, and the handling of the edge case of there being no decimal part, where `3` as a double prints as `3.` - if the result is a blank (guaranteed by the second parameter to split) which is then converted to a zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
  double d = 1.9;
  String str = Double.toString(d);
  String strArray[] = str.split("\\.");

  int a = Integer.parseInt(strArray[0]);
  int b = Integer.parseInt(strArray[1]);
  System.out.print(a + " - " + b);
```

Try this. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work for almost any length of the fractional part and doesn't use strings.
For example the accepted answer doesn't work for 0.16

```
double d = 123.456

long a = (long) d;
double f = d - a;

while (Math.abs((long) f - f) > 0.000001) f *= 10;

long b = (long) f;

// a = 123
// b = 345
```

Comment: @JrChen Well, it used to not work, now it's using `String` instead

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
double d=1.9;
int a;
int b;

a = (int) d/10;
b = (int) d%10;

System.out.print("a");
System.out.print("b");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    double dub=1234.5678987;//Variable to be manipulated
    long lon=0; //To store before decimal point.    
    short sh=0;//To store after decimal point.  
    int deci=10000; //to 4 decimal places   
    lon=(int)dub;// get the integer part of the number stored in long   
    sh=(short)((dub-(double)lon)*deci);//deci to required decimal places.
    System.out.println(""+lon+"."+sh);
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried a split on "." and then just parse the string for integers.

```
        String a="";
        double x = 2.4;
        a=x+"";
        String [] v =a.split("\\.");
        int before = Integer.parseInt(v[0]);
        int after = Integer.parseInt(v[1]);
```

Comment: you gotta make `a` first

Comment: I did make the "a" first

Comment: where is it initialized?

Comment: Thank you for that,as I was writing the code in I deleted more than I should have.Sorry again

Comment: This is a not very elegant way of putting a double in a String variable

Comment: I do realise this but as I said it was the first thing that came to mind

Comment: Try `String a = Double.toString(x)`!