# Take the decimal part of a double/float number

Tags: java

I have a simple question, I want to know how can I get the decimal part from a double/float number without the dot.
Example: a=0.75 and b=3231.0131
So I would like to set those decimal values in two new Integer variables: m=75 and b=0131.

I'm going to clarify some things, I want to create a new int variable, that variable will storage the decimal part from the original number.

```
double a = 0.75
double b = 12.033
int x = decimalofa
int y = decimalofb

System.out.println("the decimal of"+a+"is"+x+"and the decimal of"+b+"is"+y)
//the decimal of 0.75 is 75 and the decimal of 12.033 is 033
```

The thing is that i'm not sure if 033 could be considered as an integer number, so in other words I just want to take all the numbers next to the point and save them in a new variable.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to strip leading zeroes? So that 1.1, 1.01 and 1.001 would all become 1?

Comment: it seems weird what you want to do , in your example 131 would end up being a bigger number than 75, but it was a smaller number originally

Comment: Think again about your requirements. Is this really what you want to do?

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753177/how-to-split-a-double-number-by-dot-into-two-decimal-numbers-in-java

Comment: I just want to get the decimal part of the number, so in the number 3231,0131 the decimal would be 0131 right?

Comment: @Santiago no. When you represent it as an integer, it is 131.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
    float a = 0.75f;

    System.out.println(Float.toString(a).split("[.]")[1]);
```

This only works if there is a decimal and there are numbers after that decimal

Comment: If there are no decimals `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala yes, that's why I said in the answer this only works if there is a decimal and there are numbers after it

Comment: No it won't give an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` even when there are no decimals. Because a `float` will always have a decimal point(`0.0`) even its not mentioned. My mistake!