# Using Gson with a path

Tags: java, json, gson, jsonpath

Using a simple Json file e.g:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

I want to be able to get the `JsonArray` named `menuitem` using a path:

```
String path =  "menu.popup.menuitem"
```

I tried to do this using:

```
public static JsonElement fromString(String json, String path) throws JsonSyntaxException {
        JsonObject obj = GsonBuilder.create().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
        String[] seg = path.split(".");
        for (String element : seg) {
            if (obj != null) {
                obj = obj.get(element).getAsJsonObject();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return obj
}
```

with:

```
JsonElement jsonElement = fromString(json, path);
```

But when I try `isJsonArray()` the return value is `false`. When doing the extra sanity check using `Gson.toJson(jsonElement)` the output is the full json String (above) that was inputted originally.
What's going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string split with "." (dot)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833008/java-string-split-with-dot)

Comment: Use, eg, `;` instead of `.`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`split` uses regex to find places on which string should be split, but `.` in regex is special character which represents "any character beside line separators", which means that you are actually splitting on each character. So for string like

```
"foo"
```

`"foo".split(".")` will split on `f`, `o`, `o`

```
"foo"
 ^^^
```

which means you will get as result array with four empty strings (3 splits give 4 elements).

```
["", "", "", ""]
```

Actually I lied here because `split(regex)` does one additional thing: it removes trailing empty strings from result array, but your array contains only empty strings, which means that they will all be removed, so `split(".")` will return just empty array `[]` so your loop will not iterate even once (that is why your method returns unmodified `obj`).

To get rid of this problem you will need to make `.` literal (you need to escape it). To do so you can use for instance `split("\\.")` or `split("[.]")` or `split(Pattern.quote(".")` which work same as `split("\\Q.\\E")` - it adds quotation area.

Also inside loop you should first check type of Json you are handling, because `getAsJsonObject` will fail if Json is array. So your code should probably look like

```
public static JsonElement fromString(String json, String path)
        throws JsonSyntaxException {
    JsonObject obj = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
    String[] seg = path.split("\\.");
    for (String element : seg) {
        if (obj != null) {
            JsonElement ele = obj.get(element);
            if (!ele.isJsonObject()) 
                return ele;
            else
                obj = ele.getAsJsonObject();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively path.split("[.]")  can also be used as enclosing in [ ]  depicts a literal character

Comment: @prash Yes, which is already mentioned in the answer, along with few other ways :)

Comment: wow such a detailed one it is! .. Sorry i dint notice I just checked the code section .. ty for pointing out :-)

Comment: I tried running it with :
'{"menu":{"id":"file","value":"File","popup":{"menuitem":[{"value":"New","body":{"services":[{"id":"7d45d915-2e91-4d75-810f-c389339050cb"}]}}]}}}'

tried to extract with "menu.popup.menuitem" and it failed

Comment: @AviC Worked for me. Calling `fromString(json, "menu.popup.menuitem")` returns array containing `[{"value":"New","body":{"services":[{"id":"7d45d915-2e91-4d75-810f-c389339050cb"}]}}]` which seems to match to what you wanted.

Comment: Pshemo ,thanks it did work , is it possible to preform modification on json using dotted path using same approach ?i.e remove

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure why this is not built-into Gson, but here is a method that I wrote, which returns a [JsonElement](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) given a JsonElement input and a JSON Path:

```
/**
 * Returns a JSON sub-element from the given JsonElement and the given path
 *
 * @param json - a Gson JsonElement
 * @param path - a JSON path, e.g. a.b.c[2].d
 * @return - a sub-element of json according to the given path
 */
public static JsonElement getJsonElement(JsonElement json, String path){

    String[] parts = path.split("\\.|\\[|\\]");
    JsonElement result = json;

    for (String key : parts) {

        key = key.trim();
        if (key.isEmpty())
            continue;

        if (result == null){
            result = JsonNull.INSTANCE;
            break;
        }

        if (result.isJsonObject()){
            result = ((JsonObject)result).get(key);
        }
        else if (result.isJsonArray()){
            int ix = Integer.valueOf(key) - 1;
            result = ((JsonArray)result).get(ix);
        }
        else break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

To call it, use something like:

```
String jsonString = ...;

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject  jsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class);
JsonElement subElement = getJsonElement(jsonObject, "a.b.c[2].d";
```

Comment: It's not baked into Gson because there is a separate, more formal way of doing it called JSON Path. Here is one popular implementation https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath and here is the introduction to it https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket in line 5.