# How to find words(strings) with only Uppercase letters?

Tags: java, string, uppercase

I was wondering, is there any function or way, how to select from a random text all words(strings) with only uppercase letters? To be more specific, I want to take from text all uppercase words and put them into an string array, because those uppercase words are important for me.

For example from text: `"This text was just made RANDOMLY to show what I MEANT."`

In string array I will have words `RANDOMLY` and `MEANT`.

And array should looks like this `String[] myArray = {"RANDOMLY", "MEANT"};`

The only thing I think of is that I have go trought every single letter and check if its uppercase,

if yes

- save the letter to a string variable
- increase value of help integer variable (`int count`) by one
- and take a look at the next letter,

  - if its uppercase again, repeat this part
  - if not - move to another letter.

I think my solotion is not very effective, so can  tell me your opinion about it? Or prehaps how to make it more effective?

PS: `int count` is there for expelling short words with 3 letters and less.

Comment: Can we assume some minimal length of words you want to find? For instance do you consider `I` as correct word? Also should `U.S.A` be counted as word?

Comment: Letters ending with . (dot)  shouldnt be considered. Same goes for words with less than 4 letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably easiest way to achieve it would be using regex like `\b[A-Z]{4,}\b` which represents

- `\b` [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) - place between alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters
- `[A-Z]` [character in range](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `A-Z`
- `{4,}` which appears at least 4 times (if we don't want single letter words like `I` to be counted) (more info at: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
- `\b` another word boundary to make sure that we are reading entire word

So your code could look like:

```
String s = "This text was just made RANDOMLY to show what I MEANT.";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Z]{4,}\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    String word = m.group();
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Beside printing word to console you can also store it in `List<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

Split your sentence by whitespace. Then you can use `StringUtils.isAllUpperCase(CharSequence cs)` for instance to check every single string.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAllUpperCase(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: don't forget punctuation

Comment: To expand for OP: To split your sentence, use `String[] splitString= myString.split("\\s+");` Then you can iterate over the contents in the splitString, and check for `isAllUpperCase(splitString[i])`

Comment: I had problems with importing libs at first but this work good aswell! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex to extract them. Like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        String dataStr = "This text was just made RANDOMLY to show what I MEANT.";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][A-Z]+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dataStr);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            words.add(matcher.group());
        }

        System.out.println(words);
    }
```

Output:

```
[RANDOMLY, MEANT]
```

With this in future, you could just adjust search pattern to extract what ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with minimal use of regex.

```
String s = "This text was just made RANDOMLY to show what I MEANT.";
    String[] words = s.split(" |\\.");
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String word : words) {
        String wordToUpperCase = word.toUpperCase();
        if(wordToUpperCase.equals(word)) {
            result.add(word);
        }
    }
```

The line of code:

```
String[] words = s.split(" |\\.");
```

means that the string will be split either by a white-space (" ") or by a dot(".")

More info on why the dashes (escaping) were needed here: [Java string split with "." (dot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833008/java-string-split-with-dot)

If you would have split the string just by white-space, as such:

```
String[] words = s.split(" ");
```

it would have left possible nasty results like "MEANT."

In either case, the word "I" is included in the result. If you don't want that, make a check so that every word has a length greater that 1.