# Split String 2 times but with different splits ";" and "."

Tags: java, arrays, string

Original String: "12312123;www.qwerty.com"

With this `Model.getList().get(0).split(";")[1]`

I get: "www.qwerty.com"

I tried doing this: `Model.getList().get(0).split(";")[1].split(".")[1]`

But it didnt work I get exception. How can I solve this?

I want only "qwerty"

Comment: You'd need to escape the `.`, i.e. `"\\."`. Period is a special character in regular expressions, meaning "any character".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833008/java-string-split-with-dot

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `split(";|\\.")` like this:

```
 for (String string : "12312123;www.qwerty.com".split(";|\\.")) {

        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

Output:

```
  12312123
  www
  qwerty
  com
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, to achieve "qwerty":

```
Model.getList().get(0).split(";")[1].split("\\.")[1]
```

You need escape dot symbol

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string which has multiple delimiters. Example below:

```
String abc = "11;xyz.test.com";
String[] tokens = abc.split(";|\\.");
System.out.println(tokens[tokens.length-2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `array index 1` part doesn't make sense here. It will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception or something of the sort.

This is because splitting based on "." doesn't work the way you want it to. You would need to escape the period by putting "\." instead. You will find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that "." means something completely different.

Comment: @IdontwearString Most of the answers here will work for your case. Please mark whichever one explains this best, so that people can get to the correct answer sooner, in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to escape the `.`, i.e. `"\\."`. Period is a special character in regular expressions, meaning "any character".

What your current split means is "split on any character"; this means that it splits the string into a number of empty strings, since there is nothing between consecutive occurrences of " any character".

There is a subtle gotcha in the behaviour of the `String.split` method, which is that it discards trailing empty strings from the token array (unless you pass a negative number as the second parameter).

Since your entire token array consists of empty strings, all of these are discarded, so the result of the split is a zero-length array - hence the exception when you try to access one of its element.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use split, use a regular expression (directly). It's safer, and faster.

```
String input = "12312123;www.qwerty.com";
String regex = "([^.;]+)\\.[^.;]+$";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // prints: qwerty
}
```