# java regex for separating by space or capture content in " "

Tags: java, regex

Getting used to regex here.

I have a file in the structure of

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 "word6" "word7"
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 "word6" "word7"
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 "word6" "word7"
...
```

which I want to capture into:

```
arr[0] = word1
arr[1] = word2
arr[2] = word3
arr[3] = word4
arr[4] = word5
arr[5] = word6
arr[6] = word7
```

My regex is: `(?m)(.* )(.* )(.* )(.* )(.* )(".*") (".*")`

Now I'm sure there is a more elegant way to write this where I don't have to repeat the same sequence multiple times.

My understanding is something like this should work?

```
(?:(.* )*|(".*")*)
```

I believe `(?:(.* )|(".*"))` means match EITHER `.*`  or `".*"` and the `*` at the end of `(.* )` and `(".*")` forming `(.* )*` and `(".*")*` means match 0 or more times. This should do the same thing as my ***working regex*** no?

Thoughts?

**EDIT**
After reading everything, I was simply trying to shorten my regex by capturing based on (.*) or \"(.*)\" without specifying the number of times the capturing will occur which is not possible. thank you!

the correct regex: `(?m)(.*) (.*) (.*) (.*) (.*) \"(.*)\" \"(.*)\"`

Comment: Why don't you just use the built-in String.split() function? So, String[] arr = lineInput.split(" ");

Comment: Do you **need** to capture each word ? Or do you just want to match them ? Because if you want to capture them, you need to write each capture group specifically

Comment: What is a word for you? What characters are allowed?

Comment: @khriskooper because I need to split by a space OR " " and I know I could do something to make it work but I want to get better at regex

Comment: @Gawil match as in figuring out whether they exist? and capture as in get the value? unsure of the terminology

Comment: @Toto word as in either words (alphanumeric) or filepaths (UNIX and windows) so I just used `.*`

Comment: @ShiZhang please, put the word definition into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have a group repeating by * or +, it will still be taken only once - the last time when it matches. Alas, we have to write such groups many times.
2. Space is done by \s
3. (.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s"(.*)"\s"(.*)"

is enough. You mustn't put `"` IN groups, according to your task. Your regex is NOT working, taking `"` and spaces into arr[6] and arr[5].

4. [Example](https://regex101.com/r/PGS3oS/1)

If you want to read words independently on if they are in "" or not, and number of spaces between words can be any, then:

```
[\s"]*(\w+)[\s"]+(\w+)[\s"]+(\w+)[\s"]+(\w+)[\s"]+(\w+)[\s"]+(\w+)[\s"]+(\w+)[\s"]*
```

Really, it is the shortened variant, for this way we cannot check for presence of "" on both sides of the words.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/PGS3oS/3)

If you really want to take arbitrary number of words, use split() function, splitting by spaces `\\s?` and after that trimming off excessive " and/or spaces from the elements.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833008/java-string-split-with-dot/14833048#14833048) for example.

It is impossible to split lines into arbitrary number of groups by regex only, without split() or something similar.

Comment: you wrote **It is impossible to split lines into arbitrary number of groups by regex only, without split() or something similar.** does that mean what I was trying to accomplish with `(?:(.* )*|(".*")*)` is not possible?

Comment: after reading everything, including the bottom answer, I was simply trying to **shorten** my regex by capturing based on `(.*)` or `\"(.*)\"` **without specifying the number of times the capturing will occur** which is not possible. thank you!

Comment: @ShiZhang Please, distinguish matching and capturing - matching is about finding a piece in the line that corresponds to regex. It can use undefined or defined repeaters. Capturing is taking all pieces that correspond to regex groups. When you use repeater for a group #2, for example, it captures many found pieces one after another into the same result #2. Naturally, only the last one remains there.

Comment: @ShiZhang sO, It IS possible to use repeaters for groups, only they won't work as you expected. -Sigh- For me it was a great disappointment, too.