# How to convert an IP string to an array of integers in java?

Tags: java, ip

I'm trying to make an array of integers from an IP string in java.
For example:

```
String ip = "192.168.0.1";
int[] ipArray = new int[4];
int[0] = 192; int[1] = 168; int[2] = 0; int[3] = 1;
```

any idea how can I do this?

I know the parseInt tool, but how can I work with the "." ?

Sorry the noob question, I'm still a beginner.

Comment: Split the string with . (dot) and then apply parseInt

Comment: `int[] ipArray = Arrays.stream(ip.split("\\.")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your string by `.` sign. Solution using Java 8 Streams :

```
int[] ipArray = Arrays.stream(ip.split("\\."))
                .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
                .toArray();
```

**EDIT**

`Integer::parseInt` might be better here as it returns primitive `int` instead of `Integer` like `Integer::valueOf` does. So to avoid unnecessary unboxing :

```
int[] ipArray = Arrays.stream(ip.split("\\."))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method.

For example:

```
String str = "192.168.0.1";
String[] strSplit = str.split("\\.");
int[] intArray = new int[strSplit.length];
for(int i=0; i<intArray.length; i++){
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strSplit[i]);
}
```

The reason for `\\.` is because `.` is a special character in [Java Regex Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833008/java-string-split-with-dot). Otherwise if the string was split with brackets, then `str.split("-")` would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help!